# Add binding to static class Math in graal context

Tags: java, graalvm, graaljs

I use e.g.

```
context.getBindings("js").putMember("thing", new Thing(this));
```

to define a variable for my javascript.

How can I expose Java's `Math` """"object""""?

I can't do

```
context.getBindings("js").putMember("math", Math);
```

nor

```
context.getBindings("js").putMember("math", new Math());
```

(bc the constructor is private)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even using reflection [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65938087/3310334) to pass it

> ```
> Constructor[] cs = Math.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
> cs[0].setAccessible(true);
> Math m = (Math) cs[0].newInstance();
> context.getBindings("js").putMember("math", m);
> ```

Doesn't work in the end, because graaljs doesn't make static properties of Java host objects visible to the JavaScript.

So the solution is to use the `.static` property of `Math.class`

> ```
> context.getBindings("js").putMember("math", Math.class);
> System.out.println(context.eval("js", "math.static.toRadians(180)")); // prints 3.141592653589793
> ```

As I learnt [here](https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/issues/414)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/issues/414, you need to:

- expose `Math.class` and then access `math.static.toRadians()`
- enable HostAccess on the Context you are using

The working example thus is:

```
try (Context ctx = Context.newBuilder("js").allowHostAccess(HostAccess.ALL).build()) {
        ctx.getBindings("js").putMember("math", Math.class);
        ctx.eval("js", "print(math.static.toRadians(180));");
        ctx.close();
}
```