# Generate an instantiable class based on a static class reflectively

Tags: java, reflection

Can I (using reflection I presume?) create a class with all the same method names as `java.lang.Math` and each method just forwards it to `Math`?

E.g.

```
public class MyMath {
  public MyMath() {}

  public double abs(double a) {
    return Math.abs(a);
  }

  public float abs(float a) {
    return Math.abs(a);
  }

  public int abs(int a) {
    return Math.abs(a);
  }

  ...

  public double acos(double a) {
    return Math.acos(a);
  }
  
  ...
```

How could I generate this programmatically?

Comment: Write a program that outputs that `.java` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with reflection to get an instance of class Math:

```
try {
    Constructor[] cs = Math.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
    cs[0].setAccessible(true);
    Math m = (Math) cs[0].newInstance();
    //e.g.
    System.out.println(m.sqrt(16));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Whether this is a sensible thing to do is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. However, not the way you want it to be I'm afraid.

There are some libraries that you can use to generate dynamic classes at runtime (such as [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib)). In order to do so, first, you must define an interface that contains every method definition in `Math` class.

Here is an example:

```
public interface MathProxy
{

    double cos(double a);

    double tan(double a);

    double log(double a);

    double log10(double a);

    double sqrt(double a);

    double cbrt(double a);

    double pow(double a, double b);

    double random();

    // other methods are listed as well

}
```

Then, using cglib, you can create a proxy object that delegates all methods to the original Math class:

```
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MathEnhancer
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
        enhancer.setSuperclass(MathProxy.class);
        enhancer.setCallback(new MethodInterceptor()
        {
            @Override
            public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable
            {
                Method actualMethod = Math.class.getDeclaredMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
                return actualMethod.invoke(null, args);
            }
        });

        MathProxy mathProxy = (MathProxy) enhancer.create();
        System.out.println(mathProxy.pow(2, 8));
    }

}
```

This will print out `256.0` to console.

Comment: You could just use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` and avoid the weird dependency. But as you point out, you have to write the interface anyway so there really is little point.

Comment: This is true. However, cglib is more preferable than the standard Proxy class in many ways. For example, proxied classes are subclasses of ```java.lang.reflect.Proxy```, while enhanced classess extend whichever type you specify. Also, proxied classes are final. On the other hand, you can extend enhanced classes as many times you want.